# Empty columns when querying

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-query-tool

When using the Invantive Query Tool to request the table `GLTransactionlines` on Exact Online, my query times out.

When selecting a single column the query returns no data. Specifically, I would like to know from what table I can request my Transaction Lines.

I have used the following query:

```
select division_code
,      gltransaction_date
,      gltransaction_journal_code_attr
,      glaccount_code_attr
,      amount_value
,      glaccount_balancetype_attr
from   gltransactionlines
where  glaccount_balancetype_attr = 'W';

local export results as "${rptoutpath}\TransactionsPLlsc.xlsx" format xlsx
```

When I select `*`, the Invantive Query Tool returns that there are too many columns in `GLTransactionLines`.

The exact error is:

```
De externe server heeft een fout geretourneerd: (401) Niet gemachtigd.
```

It occurs after ten minutes. When I let run DebugView along, it shows me that the following URL does not return:

```
Load Exact Online data using URL 'https://start.exactonline.nl/Docs/XMLDownload.aspx?Topic=gltransactions&Params_details=1&Params_documents=0&_Division_=1362280'
```

When I try to export another Exact Online table, it works. And sometimes fetching the GLTransactionLines works too.

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41140210/993547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the XML API of GL Transaction Lines is slow or malfunctioning on your environment. Please contact your supplier about this. As an alternative, you might want to switch to using the REST API which contains similar data, such as:

```
select *
from   TransactionLines 
where  financialyear = 2016
and    financialperiod = 12
```